# Fullcalendar 5 how to hide scrollbar

Tags: scrollbar, fullcalendar-5

How to hide scrollbar in fullcalenda 5. In fullcalenda 4 i can set `overflow: hidden` to `.fc-scroller` but in 5 scrollbar is hidden but all cals is based on visible scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

Tricky solution. In css add selector:

```
html body > div:not([id]):not([class]) {
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```